# I-Phone: Trying to check an Array for an item based on a string produced

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, string

I'm writing a program that will concatenate a string based on letters, and then check an array to see if that string exists. If it does, then it will print a line in IB saying so.

I've got all the ins-and-outs worked out, save for the fact that the simulator keeps crashing on me!

Here's the code:

```
-(IBAction)checkWord:(id)sender
{
NSMutableArray *wordList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"BIKE", @"BUS", @"BILL", nil];


if([wordList containsObject:theWord])
{
NSString *dummyText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ is a real word.", theWord];
checkText.text = dummyText;

[dummyText release];
}

}
```

"theWord" is the string that is being referenced against the Array to see if it matches an item contained within it. In this case "BIKE" is 'theWord'.

Thank you for your help in advance!

-MB

Comment: So the problem is that it crashes when you click the checkWord button?  What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Are you sure the arrayWithObjects line in the posted question is exactly how it is in the actual code?  Update the question with the exact code if it is different.  If it is exact, add a NSLog(@"hello"); as the first line in checkWord and see if that prints before crashing.

Comment: You should add comments or update the question instead of adding Answers.  Anyway, it sounds like the problem is somewhere else in your code.  Double check what method is hooked up to the checkWord button in IB.  Make sure IB and the code are in sync.  Is there anywhere else in your code you are calling arrayWithObjects?

Answer (score 1):

The variable "checkText" is a UILabel that is being linked 'dummyText'. It is defined as retain,nonatomic.

```
-(IBAction)checkWord:(id)sender
{
NSArray *wordList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"BIKE", @"BUS", @"BILL", nil];


if([wordList containsObject: theWord])
{
    NSString *dummyText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ is a real word.", theWord];
    checkText.text = dummyText;
    [dummyText release];
}
else{

    NSString *dummyText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ is not a real word.", theWord];
    checkText.text = dummyText;
    NSLog(@"NOT A WORD");
    [dummyText release];
}

[wordList release];

}
```

I'm wondering if the containsObject is supposed to be a BOOL statement? If so, how would I phrase it?

Here is how checkText and theWord are defined in the header file for the project.

```
 @interface blah blah {
 IBOutlet UILabel *checkText;
 NSString *theWord;
 }
 @property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *checkText;
 @property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *theWord;
 @end
```

This isn't the whole file, just a demonstration of how the variables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the console says:

```
2010-03-20 21:01:42.822 Button_fun[5563:207] *** -[__NSPlaceholderArray arrayWithObjects:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3906450
2010-03-20 21:01:42.823 Button_fun[5563:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray arrayWithObjects:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3906450'
2010-03-20 21:01:42.823 Button_fun[5563:207] Stack: (
29295707,
2547500297,
29677627,
29247094,
29099714,
12827,
2724869,
3132238,
3140975,
3136187,
2829791,
2738120,
2764897,
37391705,
29080448,
29076552,
37385749,
37385946,
2768815,
10484,
10338
)
```

And yes, the application automatically quits when the "Check Word" button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

How have you defined your `checkText` property? As an `NSString` property, is it set to `copy`, and not `retain`?

P.S. Don't create answers to your own question to add in more information. Edit your original question instead.